# Como organizar mensagens dos formulários em projeto Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic

Estou tendo uma dúvida em relação à melhor maneira de organizar minhas mensagens de erro dentro do Ionic 3 usando o Angular 6.

Criei dentro do meu recovery-passwrod.ts um array de mensagens :

```
  validation_messages = {
'cpf': [
  { type: 'required', message: 'O CPF precisa ser preenchido' },
  { type: 'minlength', message: 'O campo de CPF precisa ter no mínimo 11 digitos' },
  { type: 'maxlength', message: 'O campo de CPF precisa ter no máximo 11 digitos' },
  { type: 'pattern', message: 'O campo de CPF deve conter apenas números' },
]}
```

Dentro do meu recovery-password.html chamei o tratamento do formulário dessa maneira:

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="formRecoveryPass">
      <div class="form-group">

        <ion-item>
          <label>CPF</label>
          <ion-input type="text" placeholder="CPF" [(ngModel)]="userModel.cpf" [brmasker]="{mask:'000.000.000-00', len:14}"  formControlName="cpf"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.cpf">
          <div *ngIf="formRecoveryPass.controls['cpf'].hasError(validation.type) && formRecoveryPass.controls['cpf'].dirty && formRecoveryPass.controls['cpf'].touched">
            {{ validation.message }}
          </div>
        </ng-container>


      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" [disabled]="!formRecoveryPass.valid">Resetar senha</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Minha questão é quanto à repetição de código em outra situações que eu provavelmente usarei o campo de CPF. Como eu poderia organizar as mensagens de tratamento dos inputs ?

Minha ideia era ter um repositório para reunir todas as possíveis mensagens para cada campo. Seria possível?

Qual a melhor maneira? Usando components?

Comment: Voce pode ter uma função que mapeia o erro do form pra sua mensagem no mesmo lugar que vc tem o validation_messages.

Comment: Perfeito Eduardo, mas seria melhor usar como um componente? Meu objetivo é ter um "repositório" de mensagens e poder usar em diferentes componentes ou pages.. Minha dúvida é sobre a melhor forma de "importar" essa "função"... Seria um component, um pipe, uma diretiva...